# passing objects to other objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, scope

I have an object objOne and another objTwo, defined thus (please note the comment where I have the question):

```
function objOne(varA, varB) {
    this.varA = varA;
    this.varB = varB;
}

objOne.prototype = {
    constructor: objOne,
    funcA: function() {
        //do stuff
    }
}

function objTwo(varA) {
    this.varA = varA;
}

objTwo.prototype = {
    constructor: objTwo,
    funcB: function() {
        //do stuff
        //NEED TO USE objOne's instance's funcA here
    }
}
```

I am developing in NodeJS. In my server.js, I made an instance of objOne and objTwo:

```
objOne = new objOne(a, b);
objTwo = new objTwo(c);
```

How do I make objOne available for objTwo? This way is the only way that worked:

```
//modifed objTwo constructor:
function objTwo(varA, objOne) {
    this.varA = varA;
    this.objOne = objOne;
}
```

then in the definition for funcB:

```
funcB: function() {
    this.objOne.funcA();
    //do other stuff
}
```

but this has the nasty side effect of making my objTwo have objOne as one of its members, which I do not want.

Is there a more elegant way of making funcA available in funcB without associating objOne with objTwo?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it's the right way. Unless objOne and objTwo are singletons (only one instance will ever exists for the duration of the program), in which case you can put them somewhere else.

Comment: objOne should be a singleton, but not objTwo. The problem is when i'm passing objTwo around I do not want objOne to make the rounds with it haha. It forces me to make yet another object, objThree, that inherits stuff from objTwo without inheriting objOne as well. is that the right approach?

Comment: Make `objOne` a base object and let `objTwo` inherit from its prototype?

Comment: I think you need to use real examples here. A, B, C don't give enough information. Why does objTwo.funcB need to call objOne.funcA?

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple way:

```
function objOne(varA, varB) {
    this.varA = varA;
    this.varB = varB;
}

objOne.prototype = {
    constructor: objOne,
    funcA: function() {
        //do stuff
    }
}

function objTwo(varA) {
    this.varA = varA;
}

objTwo.prototype = {
    constructor: objTwo,
    funcB: function(objOne) { // Pass objOne at the function call
        //do stuff
        //NEED TO USE objOne's instance's funcA here
    }
}
```

This is the only way I see anyway.

If you want to use OOP in javascript in a more professional and confortable environment (classes, inheritance, interfaces, dependency injection, ...) I would suggest you to use a framework helping you to really handle OOP (because native javascript is a bit light on the subject). You can give a look at [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf) for example or google it!